# What permissions are needed to bind a tunneled ssh port on the "remote end" post connection? Error is "bind [127.0.0.1]:<port> Permission denied"

Tags: security, permissions, ssh-tunnel, bind, fedora-38

As many others have encountered, I've got a system behind a "remote" DHCP router that needs to connect reliably with a "local" system using reverse port mapping for various reasons - fundamentally it's for backup and maintenance.

Happily, I had it working just fine using an outbound connection using ssh to establish a connection to my "local" Fedora Servers.

Unhappily, it then stopped working.

What changed? An upgrade on the local system(s) from, oh, I'm not sure what version of Fedora, but maybe as old as 28 or so; I just replaced it all with a new setup on Fedora 38.

The setup is "exactly the same", but obviously it isn't!

The "remote" system uses:

```
ssh -N -R :<port>:localhost:22 <user>@<local_system>
```

The "remote" side sees:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port <port>
```

The "local" side, in `/var/log/secure`, sees:

```
May 30 18:18:38 server1 sshd[45591]: Accepted publickey for <user> from <remote_IP> port 41158 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<some_key>
May 30 18:18:38 server1 sshd[45591]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user <user>(uid=<uid>) by (uid=0)
May 30 18:18:38 server1 sshd[45593]: error: bind [127.0.0.1]:<port>: Permission denied
```

OK, then: Permission denied - seems clear enough! BUT WHAT Permission, where? And how to I resolve it?

Comment: What is `<port>` exactly?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ...It's an arbitrarily selected port number that's not already in use; does it actually matter?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski HOLLY CRAP?!?! I tried a different number and it instantly worked fine?! WTF?! ...If you can simply articulate why it matters in an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as an accepted answer! :-)

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_unprivileged_port_start` (on "local")? Is the problematic port less than the output? Is the working port greater than or equal the output?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The one that's been failing was less, the one that's now working is greater. ... I have also seen where larger numbers just don't work at all, so I think a full answer about the ranges would be helpful not just to me but others... And, as apparently the modern software design anticipates, what's "unprivileged" has changed with time...

Comment: "I have also seen where larger numbers just don't work at all" – I am not able to explain this, thus not able to write a good "full answer", I think.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Partial answers are fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently in effect boundary between "privileged" (and therefore not available to `ssh`, one would presume) and "unprivileged" ports can be found by this command:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_unprivileged_port_start
```

If it's below that number, don't use it for this purpose, and above it is fine. Further, because of how it's phraised, one would presume that a port of exactly that number would be unprivileged, too, and therefore also OK.

Other facets of how this works, such as port numbers that are too large, remain unknown to this author. But, my problem was solved and maybe this will help someone else, too.